# User authentication never invoke

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I tried to authenticate user from MySQL database with BCrypt using this

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery(USER_LOGIN_QUERY).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(GET_USER_ROLE_QUERY)
            .dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}
```

on those requests here

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/reg").permitAll().anyRequest().hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()
    .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").and()
    .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
}
```

on Login page

```
<div class="login-page">
    <div class="form">
        <form class="login-form" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username"
                name="username" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"
                name="password" />
            <button type="submit">login</button>
            <p class="message">
                Not registered?
                <a th:href="@{/reg}">Create an account</a>
            </p>
        </form>
        <label th:if="${param.error}"
            class="message text-danger text-capitalize">Login
            credentials invalid</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Both overridden 'configure' methods do invoke when Web bootup. As I did put syserr to print out a random line to console from both.
I setup the datasource in application.properties and confirm it's correct since I can sign-up new user successfully. It's autowired
The USER_LOGIN_QUERY and GET_USER_ROLE_QUERY is normal too, it worked on MySQL query.
bCryptPasswordEncoder works since registering new user does encode password into hashed string. It's autowired
With jpa.show-sql = true, registering user(save to database) and other query do show SQL in the console. However, the two queries for authentication DON'T show up in the console log. So I assume login with post method never invoke authentication, hence, datasource, queries and passwordEncoder are not related
As a result, login always redirect me to failureUrl.
Where did I do wrong? How can I properly do authentication?
PS: On the other note,I follow the tutorial here https://github.com/gustavoponce7/SpringSecurityLoginTutorial , I build and run this tutorial source with no problem like above.
**UPDATE**: I tried new Spring Boot project, repeated the procedure to make a plain simple Spring Web with Security. 
 jdbcAuthentication does authenticate for sometimes but giving me SQL query error. After correcting query error, BOOMM, nothing works again, even reverting edit won't do anything.

Comment: Solved this by using UserDetailsService instead. Don't know why JdbcAuthentication doesn't work!